# How to convert a list of tuples to a matrix for column access?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
tups = [('a',5,'test'),('b', 8, 'test1')]
```

For each tuple, I need to extract the value at an index i.

Obviously, I could iterate over each tuple in the list, get the value I am after and pop it into an array... However, I think there should be a nicer way.

Ideally, I'd like to transform my list of tuples to a matrix or DataFrame (or something like that), where I can extract a column as an array.

For example, using the above list of tuples, I would like to do something like the following:

```
matrix = tups.AsMatrix(ncols=len(tups[0])) #All tups have the same number of values.
column_values = matrix[0]
print(column_values)
> 'a'
> 'b'
```

How can I do this with Python 3? I have seen Pandas has a DataFrame type, but ideally I would like to do this without using another library (other than numpy or native python).

Comment: What does "nicer" mean? If the only thing you want to do - is to extract element by index - you don't need Dataframe, of course.
If you want to do some calculations/transforms/grouping/etc - yes, dataframe is a nice tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `operator`:

```
In [250]: import operator

In [252]: f = lambda l, i: list(map(operator.itemgetter(i), l))
```

---

```
In [253]: f(tups, 0)
Out[253]: ['a', 'b']

In [254]: f(tups, 1)
Out[254]: [5, 8]

In [255]: f(tups, 2)
Out[255]: ['test', 'test1']
```

If you're using python2, drop the `list(...)`.

Comment: nice one! I keep forgetting about `itemgetter`

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you, this is what I am after!

Comment: @pookie Glad to help :)

Comment: is this faster than more pythonic list comprehension?

Comment: @Gioelelm No, but they are almost the same. This remains slower by a tiny fraction, even for very large data > 10000.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I learned something new but I would still do this with list comprehension.

Comment: @Gioelelm I respect your opinion. But as far as conciseness goes, this is pretty solid.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some custom, native Python for you:

```
tups = [('a',5,'test'),('b', 8, 'test1')]

def fetcher(list_of_tups, ind):
    return [x[ind] for x in list_of_tups]

print(fetcher(tups, 0))  # ['a', 'b']
print(fetcher(tups, 1))  # [5, 8]
```

---

Or its `lambda` version for some *fancy* points

```
f = lambda cont, i: [x[i] for x in cont]

print(f(tups, 1))  # [5, 8]
```

Comment: Hey, list comps are pretty clean too.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I like the lambda version, very concise!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
tups = [('a',5,'test'),('b', 8, 'test1')]
df = pd.DataFrame(tups)
df
```

output:

```
   0  1      2
0  a  5   test
1  b  8  test1
```